# Is Fermat's Last Theorem provable in lambda calculus

Tags: math, lambda, functional-programming

As title. I understand this is a very general question and expect someone to put it on hold, but before you do so please read:

I'm expecting answers that:

1. Directly address the question
2. Or point out where is a good place to ask this question, if not here
3. Or help me specify my question, e.g. "what does it mean for something to be provable in lambda calculus"
4. Or restate Fermat's last theorem in the form of lambda calculus
5. Or tell me what kind of flags will make this post more visible

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about lambda calculus, not a practical programming issue.  Try http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What do you mean by proving something "in lambda calculus"? Lambda calculus doesn't seem relevant to FLT.

Comment: [Curry-Howard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) does make it meaningful to say “proove maths theorem _X_ in programming language _Y_” – at least if _Y_ is a [dependently type functional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). That doesn't mean it's a good idea to ask for it on StackOverflow... even if it was a simple proof. For Fermat's last theorem, no simple proof is known; the known one uses crazy advanced maths and won't look simple in lambda calculus either.

Comment: Lambda calculus is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_complete). Thus you can calculate just about everything which is computable by machine with it. Andrew Wiles proof can be ported to it if they can be computed with any hight level language. Doing it is silly difficult, but it's probably fun. I made a fully functional Lisp interpreter in Brainfuck in just 2 summer vacations some years ago after reading [GEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach).

Comment: I'm not sure that a mathematician would consider a program to be on a par with a proof.  It's an ongoing debate in mathematics.

Comment: Thank you all, even though the voting is negative at least I got the answers to 2 & 3.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth as a functional programmer it is sad to know lambda calculus isn't "a practical programming issue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you formulate your question reasonably then the answer is "of course" by the Church-Turing Thesis and the fact that FLT is provable in Peano Arithmetic (which can be fully developed in lambda calculus).